# How to show work on binary number addition/conversion

Tags: equations

I'm doing various operations with binary numbers for my Discrete Mathematics hw and I'm not quite sure how to render it because I need to show my work.

This is an image of something I've been trying to show:

[image: screenshot]

I am also trying to add and multiply numbers and show work. I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 11):

There are probably lots of different ways of doing this- the solution below uses a simple `array` environment.

[image: screenshot]

The only subtle thing is that I've used the optional `[t]` argument to specify the vertical alignment. I've also used the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) to format the `enumerate` environment to have `roman` numbers (some might call it overkill).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}   % for customizing list environments
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\roman*.]
  \item $\begin{array}[t]{r}
        2012\\
        -1024\\\hline
        988\\
        -512\\\hline
        476\\
        -256\\\hline
        220\\
        -128\\\hline
        92\\
        -64\\\hline
        28\\
        -16\\\hline
        12
      \end{array}$
    \item $\begin{array}[t]{c|c|c|c}
        11  &   111 &   011 &   100 \\
        3   &   7   &   3   &   4
      \end{array}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

## Putting two such calculations side by side

Following the comment, there are lots of ways to put two such `array`s side by side. You could use a `minipage`, but that might require some width calculations, so an easy solution is to use a `tabular` and then nest the `arrays` inside

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}   % for customizing list environments
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\roman*.]
  \item \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
        $\begin{array}[t]{r}
        2012\\
        -1024\\\hline
        988\\
        -512\\\hline
        476\\
        -256\\\hline
        220\\
        -128\\\hline
        92\\
        -64\\\hline
        28\\
        -16\\\hline
        12
      \end{array}$
      &
        $\begin{array}[t]{r}
        2012\\
        -1024\\\hline
        988\\
        -512\\\hline
        476\\
        -256\\\hline
        220\\
        -128\\\hline
        92\\
        -64\\\hline
        28\\
        -16\\\hline
        12
      \end{array}$
    \end{tabular}
    \item $\begin{array}[t]{c|c|c|c}
        11  &   111 &   011 &   100 \\
        3   &   7   &   3   &   4
      \end{array}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Or, you might prefer to use the `aligned` environment from the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) package; the output is the same as the `tabular` solution, but it might give you an advantage with 'global' alignment if you have a lot of these calculations- take your pick :)

```
  \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
        \begin{array}[t]{r}
        2012\\
        -1024\\\hline
        988\\
        -512\\\hline
        476\\
        -256\\\hline
        220\\
        -128\\\hline
        92\\
        -64\\\hline
        28\\
        -16\\\hline
        12
      \end{array}
      & &
        \begin{array}[t]{r}
        2012\\
        -1024\\\hline
        988\\
        -512\\\hline
        476\\
        -256\\\hline
        220\\
        -128\\\hline
        92\\
        -64\\\hline
        28\\
        -16\\\hline
        12
      \end{array}
    \end{aligned}$
```

Comment: How do you align two of these arrays side by side (to save space, for example)

Comment: @Arjun see my update :)